# Non-Injective Closed Type Family

Tags: haskell, type-families, injective-function

I have this admittedly contrived chunk of code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

data Foo = Foo

type family Id (n :: Foo) a where
    Id 'Foo a = a

data Bar (n :: Foo) = Bar

class Dispatch (n :: Foo) where
    consume :: Id n a -> Bar n -> a

consume' :: Dispatch n => Id n [Bool] -> Bar n -> [Bool]
consume' = consume

consume'' :: Dispatch n => Id n [Bool] -> Bar n -> Bool
consume'' g x = and (consume' g x)
```

This compiles and works fine. However, if I replace the final `consume''` definition with

```
consume'' :: Dispatch n => Id n [Bool] -> Bar n -> Bool
consume'' g x = and (consume g x)
```

(Note the `consume` rather than `consume'`), then I get an error

```
noinject.hs:17:30: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Id n (t0 Bool)’
                  with actual type ‘Id n [Bool]’
      NB: ‘Id’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘consume’, namely ‘g’
      In the first argument of ‘and’, namely ‘(consume g x)’
      In the expression: and (consume g x)
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: Bar n (bound at noinject.hs:17:13)
        g :: Id n [Bool] (bound at noinject.hs:17:11)
        consume'' :: Id n [Bool] -> Bar n -> Bool
          (bound at noinject.hs:17:1)
   |
17 | consume'' g x = and (consume g x)
   |                              ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

If we assume `Id` is non-injective, then the error occurs because `consume` could feasibly specialize to `consume :: Id n (t0 Bool) -> Bar n -> t0 Bool`, for some foldable `t0` that isn't `[]`. I understand that much. My question is: why is `Id` *not* actually injective. It takes two arguments: there's only one valid value for the first argument, and `Id` is pretty clearly injective in its second argument, so why does GHC think this is a non-injective family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Injective type families](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_families.html#injective-type-families) are a separate extension on top of type families, and you need special syntax to declare a type family as one. Injectivity does not get inferred.

Comment: I only want to add that, in my limited experience, injective type families never solved any problem I expected them to solve ;-). Perhaps the OP's is one of those cases where they work. I recall that some trivial examples like `f :: F a ~ F b => a -> b ; f x = x` surprisingly fail to work since injectivity is not fully exploited during type checking.

Comment: @chi Unfortunately, you're right that it seems GHC still doesn't accept my type as injective even with an explicit annotation. However, this does answer my question, so thank you both for the help! :)