# Haskell NB: ‘Edge’ is a non-injective type family

Tags: algorithm, haskell, typeclass, dijkstra, type-families

I am trying to write my own graph library in Haskell for use in the advent of code. I am trying to use a class for graphs and one concrete implementation using `Data.Map`. I am trying to write Dijkstra's algorithm, but I am running into some trouble with type families. I have the following `typeclass` and concrete implementation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

class Graph g where
  type Node g
  type Edge g
  nodeSet :: g -> S.Set (Node g)
  neighbours :: g -> (Node g) -> Maybe [(Edge g, Node g)]

data MapGraph e n = MapGraph {mGraph :: M.Map n [(e,n)]} deriving Show
instance (Num e,Ord e,Ord n) => Graph (MapGraph e n) where
  type Node (MapGraph e n) = n
  type Edge (MapGraph e n) = e
  nodeSet mapGraph = S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph
  neighbours mapGraph node = M.lookup node (mGraph mapGraph)
```

To represent the `Infinity` value of unvisited nodes in Dijkstra's algorithm I have created a sum data type:

```
data MaxBoundedNum a = Inf | Num a deriving Show
```

I am trying to work on the recursive function for the algorithm which will take in the graph, the current node, the destination node, the unvisited set, and a map of nodes and their length from the source node. The following skeleton function seems to be what I want:

```
go :: (Graph g) =>
  g -> (Node g) -> (Node g) ->
  S.Set (Node g) ->
  M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g)) ->
  Maybe (M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g)))
go graph curr dest uset vals = do
  currNeighbours <- neighbours graph curr
  undefined
```

This appears to work correctly for a `graph g` where `graph :: MapGraph Int String`

```
go graph
  :: [Char]
     -> [Char]
     -> S.Set [Char]
     -> M.Map [Char] (MaxBoundedNum Int)
     -> Maybe (M.Map [Char] (MaxBoundedNum Int))
```

The next part of my `go` function needs to lookup the current distance from the `vals` map.

```
currDist <- M.lookup curr vals
```

This works outside the `go` function if I do the following:

```
currDist = M.lookup current vals

*Main> :t currDist
currDist :: Maybe (MaxBoundedNum Integer)
```

However, inside the `do` block I get this error:

```
Could not deduce (Ord (Node g)) arising from a use of ‘M.lookup’
      from the context: Graph g
        bound by the type signature for:
                   go :: forall g.
                         Graph g =>
                         g
                         -> Node g
                         -> Node g
                         -> S.Set (Node g)
                         -> M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
                         -> Maybe (M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g)))
        at WithClass.hs:(96,1)-(100,49)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: currDist <- M.lookup curr vals
```

The part `Could not deduce` made me think I need to give it a type annotation, so I did that:

```
currDist <- M.lookup curr vals :: Maybe (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
```

But that gives me this error:

```
WithClass.hs:102:15: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Edge g’ with ‘Edge g1’
      Expected type: Maybe (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g1))
        Actual type: Maybe (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
      NB: ‘Edge’ is a non-injective type family
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        currDist <- M.lookup curr vals :: Maybe (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
      In the expression:
        do currDist <- M.lookup curr vals :: Maybe (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
           currNeighbours <- neighbours graph curr
           undefined
      In an equation for ‘go’:
          go graph curr dest uset vals
            = do currDist <- M.lookup curr vals ::
                               Maybe (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
                 currNeighbours <- neighbours graph curr
                 undefined
    • Relevant bindings include
        vals :: M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
          (bound at WithClass.hs:101:25)
        uset :: S.Set (Node g) (bound at WithClass.hs:101:20)
        dest :: Node g (bound at WithClass.hs:101:15)
        curr :: Node g (bound at WithClass.hs:101:10)
        graph :: g (bound at WithClass.hs:101:4)
        go :: g
              -> Node g
              -> Node g
              -> S.Set (Node g)
              -> M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g))
              -> Maybe (M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g)))
          (bound at WithClass.hs:101:1)
```

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547887/non-injective-closed-type-family) but the accepted answer just said to add the `TypeFamilyDependencies` language extension which appears to not do anything for me. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix my code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations on `Set (Node g)` and `Map (Node g)` require you to be able to compare nodes. This is what the `Ord (Node g)` constraint represents. The type you gave for `go` says it works for *any* definition of `Node g`, even those that can't be compared. The error tells you that when you use `M.lookup`, that needs an `Ord (Node g)` constraint, but there is no way to satisfy it.

You can satisfy that constraint by adding it to the signature of `go`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleConstraints #-}  -- Also enable this extension

go :: (Graph g, Ord (Node g)) => ...
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I was wondering how it was supposed to know the constraints on the `Node` and `Edge` type, I was just assuming it was getting it implicitly from the `instance` definition. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Just for anyone coming across this I think this means my type signature of `go` should be `go :: (Graph g, Ord (Node g), Num (Edge g), Ord (Edge g)) =>
  g -> (Node g) -> (Node g) ->
  S.Set (Node g) ->
  M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g)) ->
  Maybe (M.Map (Node g) (MaxBoundedNum (Edge g)))
`